# Return class property by default

Tags: python

When having a simple class, how can I return a certain property by default without using any parentheses?

E.g. in the below, is there a way to not have to type () all the time?

```
class Person():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Bishonen'

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.name

c = Person()
print(c) # returns the object
print(c()) # actually returns the name.
```

Comment: `print(c)` does not return anything; it *writes* the string returned by the implicit call to `str(c)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to define `__str__()`. When you print, you would get the value you want.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name="John"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

p=Person()
print(p)
```

Could also use `__repr__()` to avoid needing `print()`

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name="John"
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

p=Person()
p
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I should've mentioned at the begining, that the class does not only contain simply string properties, but DataFrame's. E.g. instead of the name, it actually holds a DF. What i'd like to do then is to chain methods e.g. c.head() instead of c().head(). Any idea if this is possible, too?

Comment: @Bishonen_PL Don't show sample code that is not representative of your actual question. Change your post to show a DF instead of a simple string and show your expected output.